# What will be the Otsu's method of Thresholding (Gray Scale Image) when I will use matlab parallel toolbox?

Tags: matlab, gpu, vectorization

Global image threshold using Otsu's method. On matlab now, the Otsu command is done by

```
level = graythresh(I)
[level EM] = graythresh(I)
```

these two. But If I want to run it on GPU, by using parallel toolbox of matlab, what will be the code ?

Comment: I want to run  // T = otsurec( I, nt ); // this command by using GPU (parallel toolbox); I means Image and nt means number of threshold.

Comment: Updates should be edited into your original question. With proper code formatting, please.

Comment: Why do you want to use `graythresh` with the Parallel Toolbox? `graythresh` by itself is a very fast piece of code that takes advantage of the Intel Integrated Performance Primitives (IIPP) and most functions from the Image Processing Toolbox do take advantage. It's very fast so trying to optimize this further is a bit premature.  Donald Knuth said it best: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil.".

Comment: 1. On Graythresh , how will I pass the number of threshhold ? 2. I am using parralel toolbox for one the project, there I need to use Otsu algorithm. So should I run it on CPU only ?

Comment: @JunayedHasan did you even **try** it on CPU before wanting to use the Parallel Toolbox?  Why do you feel that there is a need for it?  `graythresh` only computes **one** threshold.  It doesn't compute multiple thresholds for multi-object segmentation.

Comment: thresh = multithresh(A,N) // I used this one... It is also used otsu's mthod as they said. Do I need to convert it on GPU ?

Comment: Why don't you try using just the CPU version first and go from there? Don't prematurely optimize if you haven't even tried the base approach.